# Мавен создает проект с ошибкой

Tags: maven

При создании пустого проекта Maven в Eclipse, система выдает ошибку. В чем причина?

Description Resource    Path    Location    Type Failure to transfer org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:pom:2.6 from repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:pom:2.6 from/to central (repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): repo.maven.apache.org pom.xml /Sara   line 1  Maven Configuration Problem

CoreException: Could not calculate build plan: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:jar:3.1: ArtifactResolutionException: Failure to transfer org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:pom:3.1 from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:pom:3.1 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): repo.maven.apache.org

Comment: Текст ошибки и логи maven в студию. Вы спрашивает то, не знаю о чем и хотите чтобы вам помогли с тем, не знаю чем?